# What to do with the "words" and "vocabulary" tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, tag-wiki

Currently we have both [words](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/words) and [vocabulary](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vocabulary) tags which seem both pretty alike and pretty vague but each have a number of questions under them.

From looking at the questions of each I couldn't quite decide exactly what semantic field they cover and how much they overlap, but when asking some questions I have myself been stumped as to what the best tags would be, even including the possibility of creating new tags; and I have gone with [vocabulary](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vocabulary) as one of my tags.

Yet I'm still fuzzy on describing what sort of question need that tag!

How do the rest of you feel? What areas should this pair cover? Should they be merged? Would somebody like to take a shot at creating the tag wiki for [vocabulary](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vocabulary) at least?

Answer (score 4):

Currently there is something wrong.  There are 122 questions tagged as [vocabulary](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vocabulary) (while 43 as [words](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/words)), but [vocabulary] is a [synonym for [words]](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/tags/words/synonyms), meaning that we cannot tag a new question as [vocabulary].

In my opinion, [vocabulary] should not have made a synonym for [words] because these tags represent different sets of questions.  Note that vocabulary can be about words, phrases, or sentences (such as proverbs).

Comment: Don't confuse whether whether two words are exact synonyms with whether two tags would make good synonyms. If you still think the questions characterised by the "words" tag are substantially different to the questions characterised by the "vocabulary" tag then you should give some details and examples. "Words" seems far too vague a tag since very few questions will not involve words, and almost none of them will be characterisable by "words". But feel free to show otherwise, maybe you are right and I just can't see it...

Answer (score 3):

Although this is not English Lanauage site but some meta questions about "words" on English.SE says that, that is kind of meta tag and should be retagged as

> Etymology, grammaticality, word-choice, meaning/semantics, slang, spelling, nouns, verbs,

So, we might need to manually retagging questions tagged with "words" to one of the above first before doing something to "words" tag.

**Note**: tag blacklisting can only be done by Stack Exchange developers, so I think we might need to raise another question or request if that needed.

ref - https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/874/removal-of-the-words-tag

Comment: It's good to discuss things even that we are not capable of doing yet.

Comment: Technically, almost every question is about "words".

Answer (score 1):

I think we should kill the [words](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/words) tag and undo the synonym for [vocabulary](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vocabulary).  As mentioned above, it's a meta tag and doesn't convey anything useful about the question.  YOU mentioned [some good examples of possible replacements that are used on the English site](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/311/162), and I think all of those are far more meaningful for describing the focus of the question.

Moreover, despite 46 and counting questions tagged [words](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/words), there are no followers, [which is a sign that the tag isn't useful or interesting enough](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3304) for anyone to want to look for [words](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/words) questions.  (Admittedly, [vocabulary](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vocabulary) is more popular and also has no followers, so you could make a case to blow away that tag as well, or the [usage](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usage) tag.)